# opencv Video-capture can not opencv rtsp

Tags: c++, opencv, rtsp, video-capture

when I was using a webcam and trying to get the rtsp stream with OPENCV::VideoCapture,but it always fails to open, I dont know how to deal with it...
Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include<opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include<opencv2/core.hpp>
#include<opencv2/highgui.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
int main(){
   string source ="rtsp://admin:1q2w3e4r@192.168.1.150:554/h264/ch1/main/av_stream";
   VideoCapture capture(source, CAP_FFMPEG);
   if(!capture.isOpened()){
      cout<<"open faiiled!!"<<endl;
   }
      Mat frame;
   while(true){
      capture>>frame;
      imshow("img.jpg",frame);
      imwrite("./outputs/img.jpg",frame);
      waitKey(0);
   }
   return 0;
}
```